# Get video URL from twitter feed using timelines/reverse_chronological

Tags: twitter, feed

I am using twitter feed API for getting feeds, I am unable to extract video URL:

https://api.twitter.com/2/users/:id/timelines/reverse_chronological

It only shows thumbnail url. I have searched a lot but does not find any work around in Reverse chronological API. How to extract video URL in this case?

```
let parameters: Parameters = [
                "max_results": "10",
                "tweet.fields": "created_at",
                "media.fields": "duration_ms,height,media_key,preview_image_url,type,url,width",
                "expansions": "author_id,attachments.media_keys",
                // Add any additional parameters as needed
            ]
```

[image]

Comment: Actually, I am developing this in Swift

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by adding "variants" in "media.fields" attribute, my new parameters are below.

```
let parameters: Parameters = [
                "max_results": "10",
                "tweet.fields": "created_at",
                "media.fields": "duration_ms,height,media_key,preview_image_url,type,url,width,variants",
                "user.fields": "id,name,profile_image_url",
                "expansions": "author_id,attachments.media_keys",
                // Add any additional parameters as needed
            ]
```

It will return variants array in "includes" -> "media" -> "variants" object, show in image below.

[image]